# AngularJS : interactive search

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, and, for a project, I need to make an interactive search engine.

So I did this for now :

**article/views/articles.html**

```
<form class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="filter-text">Text </label>
        <input type="search" class="form-control" id="filter-text" placeholder="Search for text" ng-change="applyFilter();" ng-model="filters.text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="filter-date-start">Entre </label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="filter-date-start" placeholder="Entre" ng-change="applyFilter();" ng-model="filters.date_start">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="filter-date-end">Et </label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="filter-date-end" placeholder="Et" ng-change="applyFilter();" ng-model="filters.date_end">
   </div>
</form>

<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-6">
    <div
            ng-repeat="article in articles"
            class="article"
            ng-include="'article/views/article.html'" >
    </div>
</div>
```

**article/views/article.html**

```
<div ng-hide="article.isHidden">
    <!-- My Article DOM -->
</div>
```

**article/article.js**

```
angular
.factory('articleRetriever', function ($http, $q){

    this.getLast = function( id ){

        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/articles/';
        if (id) url += id;

        return $http.get(url ,{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost:*'})
            .then(function(response) {
                var articles = [];
                for (var idx in response.data.data) {
                    var article = response.data.data[idx];
                    article.isHidden = false;
                    articles.push(article);
                }
                return articles;
            });
    };
return this;
})

.controller('ArticlesCtrl', ['$scope', 'articleRetriever', function($scope, articleRetriever) {
    $scope.articles = [];
    $scope.filters = { tag: null, date_start : null, date_end : null, text : null };
        articleRetriever.getLast()
            .then(function(arrItems){
                $scope.articlesLoaded = arrItems;
                $scope.articles = $scope.articles.concat(arrItems);
            });

    $scope.applyFilter = function () {

        var contains = $scope.filters.text.split(' ');

        for (var idx in $scope.articles) {;
            $scope.articles[idx].isHidden = true;
            if (contains.length > 0) {
                for( var jdx in contains) {
                    if ($scope.articles[idx].body.toUpperCase().indexOf( contains[jdx] ) > -1)
                        $scope.articles[idx].isHidden = false;
                    if ($scope.articles[idx].title.toUpperCase().indexOf( contains[jdx] ) > -1)
                        $scope.articles[idx].isHidden = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };

});
```

But when I fill the input with some text, the modification on `$scope.articles` didn't hide the article's div in **article/views/article.html**.
Can someone explain why and could give me a solution ?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the search form wasn't inside the div with the `ng-controller="ArticleCtrl"` directive, I moved it inside and all works perfectly now.